# SQL - Limiting And Sorting Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I am looking to answer a question "Retrieve the single ItemType that had the best profit from Monthly Sales?"

When I run my first 3 lines of code below, I get back 3 rows of data with two columns (ItemType, BestMonthlyProfit). I'm currently trying to get back one row of results and I know I have to create a HAVING statement to do this, but I am stuck on the syntax. Not sure if it involves a MAX statement of some sort. If anybody could help me, it would be appreciated.

Here's what I got (I commented out my HAVING statement below but I think it's close):

```
SELECT 
  ItemType, 
  SUM((Price - CostToMake) * Monthly Sales) AS BestMonthlyProfit
FROM Menu
GROUP BY ItemType
/* HAVING SUM((Price - CostToMake) * Monthly Sales) = */
```

Comment: What would you want to happen in the event of a tie - 2 items with the same profit?

Comment: Your question has been tagged `mysql` but you say to be using `SQL Server`. You should define what RDBMS you are really using. To get the best profit you should `ORDER BY BestMonthlyProfit DESC` and limit the result with `SELECT TOP 1` in SQL Server or `LIMIT 1` after the `ORDER BY` on MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `Having` Clause to do this use `TOP 1` with `Order by` .

```
SELECT TOP 1 ItemType, 
            SUM((Price - CostToMake) * Monthly Sales) AS BestMonthlyProfit 
FROM Menu 
GROUP BY ItemType
ORDER BY BestMonthlyProfit DESC
```

In case you want all the row's when there is a *tie* in best profit then use this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ItemType, 
            SUM((Price - CostToMake) * Monthly Sales) AS BestMonthlyProfit 
FROM Menu 
GROUP BY ItemType
ORDER BY BestMonthlyProfit DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! The TOP 1 was what I needed. I appreciate your help!!